# Update previous row

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an Excel file that contains some datas that I want to export into an Access db. In the C column I've got a field called 'Description'. Usually this field occupy just one cell, but it can happens that is more long.

[image]

In this case, for example, AP.01 has got 5 rows of description. How can update the first row with the next rows?

```
Public Sub updateDB(ByVal PathDB As String, str As String, id As Integer)
    Dim db As New cDB
    Dim v As New cVoce
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset = db.RecordSet
    v.Description = str
    db.connetti_DB(PathDB)
    db.get_rs("UPDATE Voice SET Description = '" + v.Description + "' WHERE id= '"+id+"'")

End Sub

Public Function get_rs(ByVal query As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    If db Is Nothing Then rs = Nothing : Return rs

    rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
    rs.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic

    rs.Open(query, db)
    Return rs
End Function
```

This code doesn't work because I update my current row, for this reason is useless the UPDATE instruction. How can I fix my code?

**EDIT** I post here the For loop

```
For r = 2 To grid.RowCount - 1

        vett = Split(grid(r, 1).Text)
        total = UBound(Split(grid(r, 1).Text, "."))
        If grid(r, 1).Text <> "" Then
            Select Case total
                Case 0 
                    Dim chapter As New cChapter
                    flag = 1
                    id = id + 1
                    chapter.Cod = grid(r, 1).Text.Substring(0, 1)
                    chapter.Description = grid(r, 3).Text

                    If Left(vett(0), 1) >= Chr(65) And Left(vett(0), 1) <= Chr(90) Then
                        chapter.Cod = Left(vett(0), 1)
                        oldChap = chap.Cod
                        If chapter.Cod <> oldCap Then
                            chapters.Add(chapter)
                        End If
                    End If
                    chapters.Add(chapter)
                    stringChap = chap.Description

                    Dim par As New cParagraph
                    If Left(vett(0), 2) >= Chr(65) And Left(vett(0), 2) <= Chr(90) Then
                        par.Cod = Left(vett(0), 2)
                        par.Cod_Chapter = Left(vett(0), 1)
                        oldPar = par.Cod
                        If par.Cod <> oldPar Then
                            paragraphs.Add(par)
                        End If
                    End If
                    If grid(r, 3).Text.Length > 255 Then
                        par.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString.Substring(0, 252) + "..."
                    Else
                        par.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString
                    End If
                    paragraphs.Add(par)
                    stringPar = par.Description

                Case 1 

                    flag = 2
                    id = id + 1
                    c_Voc = voc.Cod_Chapter
                    p_Voc = voc.Cod_Paragraph
                    voc.Cod_Chapter = grid(r, 1).Text.Substring(0, 1)
                    voc.Cod_Paragraph = grid(r, 1).Text.Split(".")(0)
                    voc.Cod_Voice = Right(vett(0), 2)
                    If grid(r, 3).Text.Length > 255 Then
                        voc.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString.Substring(0, 252) + "..."
                    Else
                        voc.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString
                        If voc.Description.EndsWith("-") Then
                            a = Replace(voc.Description, "-", "") 
                            voc.Description = a
                        End If
                    End If
                    stringVoice = voc.Description
                    voices.Add(voc)
                    voices.Save_DB(dbDest)

                Case 2
                    flag = 3
                    id = id + 1
                    sVoice = New cVoice
                    oldSvoice = voice.Cod_SVoice
                    sVoice.Cod_SVoice = Left(vett(0), 2)

                    If sVoice.Cod_SVoce <> oldSvoice Then
                        voices.Add(sVoice)
                        voices.Save_DB(dbDest)
                    End If

                    If grid(r, 3).Text.Length > 255 Then
                        sVoice.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString.Substring(0, 252) + "..."
                    Else
                        sVoice.Description = grid(r, 3).Text
                    End If
                    stringSvoice = sVoice.Description

                    sVoice.Cod_Voce = Left(vett(0), 5)
                    sVoice.Price1 = grid(r, 12).Text
                    sVoice.Price2 = sVoice.Price1
                    sVoice.UniMi = grid(r, 11).Text
                    sVoce.Sep = "."
                    voices.Add(sVoce)
                    voices.Save_DB(dbDest)

            End Select

        Else
            If flag = 1 Then
                stringChap = grid(r, 3).Text
                chap.Description = stringChap & grid(r, 3).Text
                stringPar = grid(r, 3).Text
                paragraph.Description = stringPar & grid(r, 3).Text
            End If

            If flag = 2 Then
                stringVoice = grid(r, 3).Text
                voc.Description = voc.Description & stringVoice
                voices.updateDB(dbDest, stringVoice, id)
                voices.Add(voc)
            End If

            If flag = 3 Then
                stringSvoice = grid(r, 3).Text
                sVoice.Description = stringSvoice & grid(r, 3).Text
                voices.Add(sVoice)
            End If
            chapter.Save_DB(dbDest)
            paragraph.Save_DB(dbDest)
            voice.Save_DB(dbDest)
        End If
    Next
```

**EDIT2** I declared id As Integer and when Code column has a value then id=id+1. In this way I always know which row I have to modify. I modified also updateDB (now I'm using 3 parameters) and I added a WHERE condition into my query. Despite the update, nothing has changed

Comment: Start by putting `Option Explicit` on top of your module and try to debug it. It will tell you which parts of your code are not correct.

Comment: But I know where is the error. When I call updateDB I'm into a For and if my index is =3 I update the third row. I don't know how to update a previous row. My code works only with the current row

Answer (score 1):

In database you cannot store records without PrimaryKey (actually you can, but it is bad idea). Since in your solution id is in fact Excel row number (sorry if I'm not correct but it looks like from code) it could be very hard to maintain it in future (in case someone add or remove description row). It would be better to change id column to text and use code as PK.
Storing description then could be solved in 2 ways:

1) Concatenate all rows containing description into 1 variable adding vbNewLine in between and store it in description field.

2) More relational but also more complex - create 2nd table for description with PK as i.e. autonumber, ForeignKey Code referring to main table. Maintenance will be here very complex. Not really worth effort.

Amount of changes in code is quite big, so sorry I'll not provide fixed code but I hope idea is clear.

BTW: The reason why description is not updated is described in your post. You are increasing id only when code is present, so every description field from first group have id = 1. The most simple fix in your code would be to create 2 update statements - One for rows with code

```
UPDATE Voice SET Description = '" + v.Description + "' WHERE id=    '"+id+"'
```

Second one for rows without code:

```
UPDATE Voice SET Description = Description + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '" + v.Description + "' WHERE id= '"+id+"'
```

Comment: The increment of id is correct. If I haven't id like a PK, I have to declare necessarily, right? I'll try to modify my code with your hints

Comment: It is not a must but good practice. And the code seems to be in your case more realiable PK (in future maybe someone will rearange rows?). But id is also OK. The main thing is that in 1 database record you should store complete data from excel (including many description lines) or think about more complex data model.